# Play2 on Scala : JSON serialization/deserialization

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I  am new Play/Scala and started porting a Spring Boot RestAPI to Play2 as a learning exercise.
In Java/SpringRest ,its simply a matter of annotating POJOs and the JSon library handle the serialize/deserialization automatically.

According to every Play2/Scala tutorial I read, I have to write a Writer/Reader for each model/case class as follows

```
implicit val writesItem = Writes[ClusterStatus] {
  case ClusterStatus(gpuFreeMemory, gpuTotalMemory, labelsLoaded, status) =>
     Json.obj("gpuFreeMemory" -> gpuFreeMemory,
              "gpuTotalMemory" -> gpuTotalMemory,
              "labelsLoaded" -> labelsLoaded,
              "status" -> status)
}

//HTTP method 
def status() = Action  { request =>
  val status: ClusterStatus = clusterService.status()
  Ok(Json.toJson(status))
}
```

This means If have a large domain model/response model, I have to write a lot of Writers/Readers for serialize/deserialization?

Is there any simpler way to handle this?

Comment: `implicit val clusterStatusFormat = Json.format[ClusterStatus]` https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

Comment: Tutorials/docs mention handwritten codecs so that you would understand how generated codecs work and what to do if generated codecs don't suit your needs. Just keep on reading and you reach that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to   "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.2". For using that you just need to do the below steps:

1) Add below dependencies(Use version according to your project):

```
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.2",
  "net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.11" % "2.6.2"
```

2) Define formats:

```
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  implicit val yourCaseClassFormat= Json.format[YourCaseClass]
```

This `format` defines both read and writes for your case class.